# exit().remove() won't remove previous content js d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```
      var datapoints = svg.selectAll('indPoints').data(filtered_up);

      datapoints
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .merge(datapoints)
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
          return x(d.callType) - jitterWidth / 2 + Math.random() * jitterWidth;
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
          return y(d.time);
        })
        .attr('r', 1.5)
        .style('fill', function (d) {
          return myColor(+d.time);
        });

      datapoints
        .transition() // and apply changes to all of them
        .duration(1000);

      datapoints.exit().remove();
```

The above code won't remove previous datapoints after I change the data (filtered_up) content.

edit:

```
      var boxes = svg.selectAll('boxes').data(sumstat);
      boxes
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr('x', function (d) {
          return x(d.key) - boxWidth / 2;
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
          return y(d.value.q3);
        })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
          return y(d.value.q1) - y(d.value.q3);
        })
        .attr('width', boxWidth)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style('fill', 'blue');
      boxes.exit().remove();
```

Same is happening for the code above. Is it something about the indPoints/boxes that are selected with the append?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
.html("");
```

example

```
d3.select('#graph').html("");
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help